# Break string in sql query at certain length and and at certain character

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I have created 2 columns datatype string,int (company,acc_id) in a ctc table which has multiple comma separated values. I need to break these string at 255 character and at comma separated character with making sure company name and account ids are not broken and make sense while reading. for achieve this query need to stop at less then 255 character if there is not enough space to include full company name and acc_ids. Also solution needs to be only in SQL query because I have to include query in third party tool  . I can not write function or stored procedure . it should break one column in 8 multiple columns each of 255 field length. Remaining empty columns can have null or empty value in it.

can some one please advise how can I achieve this .

Below is the code which is creating comma separated values in columns by concatenating multiple rows based on their email address . Duplicate rows are ok and not an issue .

```
WITH contact_CTE 
AS  
(  
    SELECT 
      acc_id,
      ,company
       ,email

   FROM table1 a
inner join table2 on b.id = a.type_id

), 

contact_CTE_Ext  
AS  (SELECT acc_id
       ,company
       email, 
      STUFF(( SELECT  ',' + company
   FROM contact_CTE as t1 
where t1.email = t2.email
FOR XML Path ('')), 1 , 1 ,'')  new_companies ,
  STUFF(( SELECT  ',' + adv_account
FROM contact_CTE as t1 
where email = Email
FOR XML Path ('')), 1 , 1 ,'')  new_accIds   
From  contact_CTE as t2  
)
```

[image: ![Actual Result]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsSWN.png)
[image: ![enter image description here]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jG5Lr.png)

Comment: Why 33333 should not be in acct_id_1? Even you put 33333 in acct_id_i, the column will not be 255 characters long

Comment: Hi Gen , it's not actual data. I am just giving example and saying that each field has 255 characters length and it can take up to 255 character and after that move on to another field.

Comment: I am confused as what the output should be and what is the logic behind it.